# SQL query for selecting records where any of a given list of integers is between columnA and columnB

Tags: sql, select, between, sql-in

How can I get records from my table where any of a list of integers is in the range defined by columnA and columnB integer values?

I know about the IN operator when comparing against a column value instead of a range defined by a pair of columns.

For example: `select * from mytable where mytable.colA in (1,3,5,6);` would get all records where colA is either 1,3,5 or 6.

Is there anything like that for ranges? Or should I do like:

`select * from mytable where 1 between mytable.colA and mytable.colb 
OR
3 between mytable.colA and mytable.colb
OR
5 between mytable.colA and mytable.colb
OR
6 between mytable.colA and mytable.colb;`

Comment: This is not particularly clear. Please provide samples of the data you are working with, along with an example of the desired results.

Comment: added examples for clarity

Comment: use greater `>` than and less `<` than for ranges: `WHERE  (mytable.colA > 1 AND mytable.colA < 6) OR (mytable.colB > 1 AND mytable.colB < 6)`

Comment: why? is there anything wrong with `between` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this way:

```sql
select distinct mytable.*
from mytable
join (select 1 nr union all select 3 union all select 5 union all select 6) n
    on n.nr between mytable.colA and mytable.colb
```

Update:

Just tested on MariaDB (10.0.19) and a 1M-row indexed table.. Your original query is ways faster.

Comment: (About your update): Interesting. I've tried both solutions on postgres (indexes on both colA and colB) and didn't find much of a difference. Anyway it's going to a periodically refreshed materialized view, so performance is not a critical issue. I was hoping for a very simple query like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE colA,colB IN (value1, ..., valueN)`, but confirmation there isn't one is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

A common tactic is to set up a temporary table, and use that to join on your main table.

A simple way to set one up is like so:

```
DECLARE @TempList table (LookFor int not null)

INSERT @TempList (LookFor) values
  (1)
 ,(3)
 ,(5)
 ,(6)
```

As this is a table, you can use querying logic to populate it.

Next up, join this into your target table. For your example above:

```
SELECT mt.*
 from myTable mt
  inner join @TempList tl
   on tl.LookFor = mt.ColA
```

And, if I'm interpreting correctly, this might be what you're really looking for:

```
SELECT mt.*
 from myTable mt
  inner join @TempList tl
   on tl.LookFor between mt.ColA and mt.ColB
```